# Site administrators values are coming as Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection in CSV

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to extract specific domain users, site and site collection administrators from web app but Site administrators column coming as Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection. Please help me to get the values of it in CSV.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $currentLocation = (Get-Location).Path $outputReport = $currentLocation + "\" + "SharePointUsers2.csv"  $UserDataCollection = @()  $WebAppsColl = Get-SPWebApplication "https://Webapp.com" foreach($WebApp in $WebAppsColl) { Write-host "Scanning Web Application:"$WebApp.Name

$SitesColl = $WebApp.Sites
foreach ($Site in $SitesColl) 
{
    Write-host "Scanning Site Collection:"$Site.URL

    $WebsColl = $Site.AllWebs

        foreach ($web in $WebsColl) 
        {
            Write-host "Scanning Web:"$Web.URL

            $UsersColl = $web.AllUsers 

                foreach ($user in $UsersColl) 
                {
                       if($User.IsDomainGroup -eq $false -and $user -notlike "*XXXXXX*" -and $user -notlike "*global*" -and $user -notlike "*SHAREPOINT*" -and $user -notlike "*AUTHORITY*" -and $user -notlike "*windows*" -and $user -notlike "*312220573*" -and $user -notlike "*true*" -and $user -notlike "*KDS*") 
                        {
                            $UserData = New-Object PSObject

                            $UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "UserLogin" -value $user.UserLogin.ToString()
                            $UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "DisplayName" -value $user.displayName.ToString()
                            $UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "E-mailID" -value $user.Email.ToString()
                            $userData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Site" -Value $user.ParentWeb.Url.Tostring()
                            $scusers = $user.ParentWeb.SiteAdministrators
                            $siteadmin = @()


                            $userData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "SC Admins" -value $user.ParentWeb.SiteAdministrators.ToString()

                            $UserDataCollection += $UserData
                        }
                }
        $Web.dispose()
        }
     $site.dispose()
    }
}    

$UserDataCollection = $UserDataCollection   #|sort-object -Property  {$_.UserLogin } -Unique 


$UserDataCollection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $OutputReport -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "Total Number of Unique Users found:"$UserDataCollection.Length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$userData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "SC Admins" -value $user.ParentWeb.SiteAdministrators.ToString()
```

This won't work, as the ToString() method does not convert the array to a string, it simply returns the type name.

You basically just need to repeat what you are doing for the $UsersColl with the $user.ParentWeb.SiteAdministrators array.

I don't have a SharePoint environment to test it on, but something like this should work

```
$admins = @()
foreach($admin in $user.ParentWeb.SiteAdministrators){
  $admins += $admin.UserLogin.ToString()
}
$userData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "SC Admins" -value ($admins -join ";")
```

Notice that you don't want to separate the generated string with commas, otherwise it will break your CSV, so instead I've used semicolons `($admins -join ";")`.